# Only images in a spinner

Tags: android, imageview, spinner

I have 4 images (`drawables`) that I want to use in a spinner.  I have found many ways to include text and images using hash maps and overriding `arrayadapter`.

They all seem very complex to handle one `ImageView` in each row.  Is there an easier way to do this?  If not how would I handle the hash map for just one `drawable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must define a layout for the row of the spinner, then create a custom arrayadapter. Look at this link

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/

I hope this helps you. BestRegards

Comment: You've been really lucky that the link didn't disappear. This answer was accepted, but one issue with that page and there would be nothing here.